# LDAP Server for development purposes on Windows 8

Tags: .net, ldap, adam, adlds

I need to test connectivity to LDAP from my application. I need something that I can easy install (preferred to be xcopy).

Years ago I was using [Active Directory Application Mode (ADAM)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4201) for this purposes. But it does not supported on Windows 8. Gives me funny error message:

```
You do not have permission to update Windows. Please contact your system administrator.
```

Now, it looks like [Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services (AD LDS)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14683). But again:

```
Installer encountered an error: 0x80096002
The certificate for the signer of the message is invalid or not found.
```

So two questions:

1. Is it possible to use AD LDS on Windows 8
2. Any other options? Quick search for example gives [OpenLDAP](http://www.userbooster.de/en/download/openldap-for-windows.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended with [OpenLDAP for Windows](http://www.userbooster.de/en/download/openldap-for-windows.aspx), just because it does not require any dependencies.

I also added it to Chocolatey

```
cinst openldap
```

Answer (score 8):

If you have Windows 8 Pro, AD LDS is included to it. 
Go to **Turn Windows features on or off**, select **Active Directory Light Weight Directory Services**.

You can also use powershell

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName DirectoryServices-ADAM-Client
```

Answer (score 1):

TurnKey Applience with OpenLDAP

http://www.turnkeylinux.org/openldap :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [ApacheDS](http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/). It was updated on May 2nd, 2013 so hope they tested it on Windows 8

Comment: Good one, but requires Java, this is additional peice to install on build server.